# Remove leading and trailing words from a string in plsql

Tags: plsql

Following is the string, and I want to remove leading and trailing 'and' word form the string.

String : and 121630 is part of ABC 9.0.2.0 and 121630 is included in DEF and

Expected output: 121630 is part of ABC 9.0.2.0 and 121630 is included in DEF

Can anyone pls tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not expert in [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1012), but this can work :) :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (' and 121630 is part of ABC 9.0.2.0 and 121630 is included in DEF and', 
                       '(^\s*and\s*(\s|$))|((^|\s)\s*and\s*$)')  
  FROM DUAL
```

EDIT:
 For more than one 'and' make a group:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (' and  and   and 121630 is part of ABC 9.0.2.0 and 121630 is included in DEF', 
                       '(^(\s*and\s*)+(\s|$))|((^|\s)(\s*and\s*)+$)')  
  FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thanks :) This is what I looked for. It works for all the three scenarios i mentioned. But there is a small issue again. It won't work for this. eg: and and 121630 is and included in DEF and. Simply i wanted to remove any number of 'and' word if occurs as leading or trailing. can you suggest a solution for this? thanks :)

Comment: @user2153047 See the EDIT

Comment: Why this solution is not working for a following String? Eg: ' , and 121630 is part of ABC 9.0.2.0 and 121630 is included in DEF,456 not applied, and 121628 is part of XYZ,123 not applied'

Comment: Because '\s' means 'space' if you want to delete ','  you can use '(\s|,)' instead '\s'. If you want to remove all non word character use \W, but this will also remove " and '. See the link, which I gave you for further details.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
      select 'and 121630 is part of ABC 9.0.2.0 and 121630 is included in DEF and' 
      from dual
    )
    select regexp_replace(str, '^and (.*) and$', '\1') fixed_str
    from tbl;

FIXED_STR
-----------------------------------------------------------
121630 is part of ABC 9.0.2.0 and 121630 is included in DEF

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary_W, But I have another question. Apart from this specific string, how to avoid 'and' word, if it is only remains as leading and/or trailing. eg1: and ABC and DEF and XYZ and. eg2: and ABC and DEF and XYZ. eg3:  ABC and DEF and XYZ and. expected output for all the three examples are : ABC and DEF and XYZ. pls suggest an answer which applies for all the three scenarios. thanks :)

Comment: Simply i wanted to remove any number of 'and' word if occurs as leading or trailing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the LTRIM and RTRIM functions:

```
declare 
  lString VARCHAR2(1000);
begin
  lString := 'and 121630 is part of ABC 9.0.2.0 and 121630 is included in DEF and';

  lString := ltrim(lString,'and ');

  lString := rtrim(lString,' and');

  dbms_output.put_line(lString);
end;
```

Comment: Why don't you add the space to the `LTRIM()`'s?

Comment: No reason other than not thinking about it really, changed it now :)